# grafana alert dashboard UID

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

when I'm trying to create the alert and add details I see that it has a dropdown for **Dasboard UID**, which I assume will render a link in the notification to open a specific dashboard, however I have no idea what to put there.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to save rule: invalid rule specification at index [0]: both annotations __dashboardUid__ and __panelId__ must be specified
```

so my dashboard URL is this
https://grafana.site.com/d/VkIxY9jnz/executerequest-error-log-analyzer?orgId=1&from=now-1h&to=now&refresh=10s

So what should become the dashboard ID and why do I need the panel ID? My dashboard has 2 panels - the chart based on loki agg query and below the raw loki data.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the dashboard UID is that part after the "d" in your URL: "VkIxY9jnz".
But I guess you've figured that out since then